# How to apply width and height and other styles to a modal created using material ui in React JS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am not able to create a material-ui modal in my React app. I could see that a modal is rendering in the browser but its not pop up as how a modal should behave. I checked the material-ui api https://material-ui.com/api/modal/ but I could not find it helpful.

Note: I do want to use a class component and NOT a functional component.

Below is the code I tried,

Here is the code sandbox: [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-hellman-3ey7j)

## index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Modal from "@material-ui/core/Modal";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal open={true} aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title">
        <div className="modal-size">
          <Typography variant="h6" id="modal-title">
            My Title
          </Typography>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

## styles.css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.modal-size {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;

  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;

  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The expected result is something like below. A modal should pop up as below.

[image: modal]

Answer (score 1):

Add the css rule `position: absolute;` or `position: fixed;` to your model-size class.

```
.modal-size {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;

  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;

  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/kind-glitter-icg05?fontsize=14)

Comment: just one quick question. Do we need to do something explicitly to close this modal popup upon clicking outside the modal popup. Or modal component is handling this internally?

Comment: Usually you pass a handler that is called when the modal is closed or dismissed, in that handler you update the value that is controlling the `open` prop of the modal.

Comment: In this case, the `onEscapeKeyDown` and `onClose` props.